# How to add checkbox with multiple values in table(WordPress)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Right now i changed from `options` table to my own table so things are getting difficult

i have a checkbox its name is `selection` in table, so here is what i tried

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="1"<?php checked("1",$item['selection']);?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="2"<?php checked("2",$item['selection']);?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="3"<?php checked("3",$item['selection']);?> />
```

This is not saving any value , Then i tried as array in below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="1"<?php checked("1",$item['selection']);?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="2"<?php checked("2",$item['selection']);?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="3"<?php checked("3",$item['selection']);?> />
```

It is throwing warning `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

How to store multiple values with the same name in checkbox when using my own table?

Any help help would be greatful.

Comment: `This is not saving any value ` you mean you are not getting values checked ?

Comment: Yep exactly,the checkbox is not checked @wordpresser

Answer (score 1):

i suppose checked  is a function and you are returning vaule with it. if thats true than you are missing an `echo` before your checked function

`<?php echo checked("1",$item['selection']);?>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1. But this is not working.the check box is not checked.i have only one field that is `selection`, so is that possible to store multiple values in this one field

Comment: When i check a multiple selection it is selecting only one which is recently selected. If there is four checkbox selected it is selecting only one out of four

Comment: In what way can i show? I don't know to show it.could you explain a bit to show it